# deviation on google map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i am using the locationUpdates demo for a test. everything is fine. i can get coordinate and address by google play services. and then i send this coordiate to third party map app through intent.

the interesing thing is that there is about 500m deviation between the mark and the exact location on google map. and almost no deviation on another map vender(baidu map in china).

In my opinion, the deviation come from two part.

1. lbs, we don't know which type google play services is using. (gps, lbs, wifi)
2. google mark a location with deviation by coordinate on purpose. because it's free i guess.

any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: you can check the network-state of the GooglePlayServices before you relese the map. have to look it up, there was a decent Checker somewhere on the internet :)

Comment: how to check the network-state of googlePlayServices? and what does is matter?

Comment: it checks for the best location-tracker available. for example, if no GPS is there, it tries the next available service with lesser precision like the local network or phonecell.